# oracle developer 10g cannot update

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-update, oracleforms

In oracle developer 10g, I have written a simple code under a button for update data as below -

```
UPDATE TAB1
SET TNAME = :BLK.v2, TDESC = :BLK.v3    
WHERE TYPEID = :BLK.v1;

COMMIT;
```

All mismatch or constraints problems already checked but when button pressed, replied "FRM-40508 : Unable to Insert Record". I have tried in different way but failed. Tried in Database directly and it was successful. I can insert data without any problem. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Is there any ORA error coming when you execute the query. try executing the query on the database directly and see if it gets executed.

Comment: read this http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_frm_40508_oracle_error_unable_to_insert_record.htm